# Como ordenar uma tabela de acordo com os dados de outra tabela

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, phpmyadmin

Tenho duas tabelas

Tabela 1

```
 create table tb1
(
  cd_tb1 INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Tabela 2

```
create table tb2
    (
      cd_tb2 INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      cd_tb1 int,
      vl_avaliacao int,

      constraint fk_tb1
      foreign key (cd_tb1)
      references tb1 (cd_tb1),
    );
```

`tb2` pode ter várias linhas com o mesmo código que pertencem a `tb1`. Preciso fazer uma média do campo `vl_avaliacao` e em seguida retornar os dados da `tb1` ordenados por essa média. Gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de fazer isso no Mysql ou se preciso retornar os valores desordenados e tentar de alguma forma ordenar na aplicação.

Comment: A tabela `tb1` tem mais algum campo além da id? O ideal seria você montar o esqueleto do seu select e depois corrigir os erros. Obs: é perfeitamente possível ordenar direto no mysql

Comment: tem sim, coloquei só o cd para deixar como exemplo

Comment: Que tal usar as opções GROUP BY e ORDER BY?

Comment: Como usar nesse contexto ?

Comment: Como eu disso acima preciso ordenar o retorno da tb1 pela media de um campo da tb2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT tb1.cd_tb1, AVG(tb2.vl_avaliacao) FROM 
tb1 LEFT OUTER JOIN tb2 ON (tb1.cd_tb1 = tb2.cd_tb1)
GROUP BY tb1.cd_tb1
ORDER BY tb1.cd_tb1;
```

Talvez possa ser de seu interesse utilizar:

```
IFNULL(AVG(tb2.vl_avaliacao), 0)
```

Comment: tentei utilizar aqui mas não funcionou, retornou apenas o cd da tb1 e o AVG da tb2 na ordem incorreta.

Comment: Tinha um erro, uma , no lugar do . em (tb1.cd_tb1 = tb2.cd_tb1). Favor corrigir.

Answer (score 0):

Complementando a resposta do colega acima (order by por média):

SELECT tb1.cd_tb1, AVG(tb2.vl_avaliacao) as Media FROM 
tb1 LEFT OUTER JOIN tb2 ON (tb1.cd_tb1 = tb2.cd_tb1)
GROUP BY tb1.cd_tb1
ORDER BY AVG(tb2.vl_avaliacao) desc;